# How can I measure if there is a significant increase in the mean over iterations?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, trend

My apologies if this is a simple question. I'm trying to measure if the average `fitness` of some variable increases over iterations. Each iteration consists of 10 `fitnesses` (discrete values), and there are 10 iterations. I've plotted the average fitness against the iteration.

How do I show whether the change in the average over time is statistically significant? The averages are all over the place; there's no clear trend by eyeballing the graphs.

EDIT: The `fitnesses` within iterations are independent. A fitness is a number between 1 and 10 assigned to a variable, and is sort of like the variable's rank, except multiple variables may have the same fitness.

In each iteration, the variables are given a fitness. These variables and their respective fitnesses are then used to make new variables for the next iteration. The process is repeated, and the experiment is to see if the fitnesses show an upward trend over iterations.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is rather unclear. What is the "fitness" of a variable? How are there 10 fitnesses for each iteration?  What is an iteration? My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you formulate this question better.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFlom, the fitness is a number between 1 and 10 assigned to each variable. It's kind of like that variable's rank, except multiple variables may have the same fitness.

Comment: Sounds like you can just use linear regression.